# High Network usage and slow download

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, download, internet-connection

Whenever I download any file in any browser, the network usage shown in task manager is always 10 times more than the actual download speed. eg. the download speed is 500 Kbps in chrome, but in task manager it shows 5 Mbps. The same is true for any other application like steam, DAP.

I am supposed to be having very fast internet, on other computer in the same network, they are able to use full potential while my laptop is reduced by 10 times the speed.

The situation is same if I use either wired or wifi connection. I use Windows 10 and have Norton Security.

Comment: Disable Windows Update Delivery Optimization, then check your download speed by using something like http://www.thinkbroadband.com/download/

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing bytes and bits? 1 byte (usually speeds within Windows and applications) = 8 bits. There is also overhead with headers etc so you will never be able to get the full headline rate

Answer (score 1):

When I download using Chrome, it displays the download in bytes per second (Bps) not bits per second (bps).  Given protocol overhead 5M bps network is pretty much the same as 500K Bps download

Comment: @Ramhound.  I think you'll find that it does answer the question.  The author seems not to have noticed that Chrome shows download speeds in Bytes not bits. And I can assure you that when doing a conversion from bytes download to bits on the wire, that a multiplier of 10 is a good order of magnitude estimatation technique. Yep

Comment: So the task manager uses bits instead? i am rather confused how the pc is able to download 4 GB file in 15 min while my laptop takes 8 hrs for the same file :/

Comment: yes Windows 10 task manager displays bits ps.  bits ps is a good merasure of network uitilisation.  Bytes ps is what the appliaction (and user) cares about so applications often use this as a measure.  There are all sorts of things that may account for the behaviour, but yoiu need to make sure you are measuring the right value.  Obviously the comparisopn of good and bad does indicat esomething wrong with the transfers to your laptop.  The best place to start is gathering evidence.  In this case you need to do a network capture with WIreshark, and work out from there.